# Join several tables for reports in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL Server databases and I'm still learning basic SQL.

Please can someone help to figure out follow problem?

My database table structure as below

[image: database schema]

Now I try to write a query to show some records from all five tables. My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT        
   Item.ItemCode, Item.ItemDescription, 
   Purchase.Date, 
   PurchaseDetails.GRNCode, PurchaseDetails.ReceivedQty, 
   Issue.Date AS Expr1, 
   IssueDetails.MRNCode, IssueDetails.IssueQty
FROM            
   Purchase 
INNER JOIN
   PurchaseDetails ON Purchase.GRNCode = PurchaseDetails.GRNCode 
INNER JOIN
   Issue 
INNER JOIN
   IssueDetails ON Issue.MRNCode = IssueDetails.MRNCode 
INNER JOIN
   Item ON IssueDetails.ItemCode = Item.ItemCode ON PurchaseDetails.ItemCode = Item.ItemCode
WHERE
   (Item.ItemCode = 10001)
```

It will produce output as below, but the problem here is some of the data is being duplicating which are highlighted

[image: actual output]

Please someone help me to execute above query to show data as below and shorting date

[image: desired output]

As my table structure is this possible to execute?

If can please someone help me to how to do.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please provide a better screen shot of your schema?  Some of the columns are not visible and I am not certain what the foreign key relationships are.

Comment: Here the Full table http://i.stack.imgur.com/HcIZl.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I took a stab at the SQL For you and here is what I've come up with:

```
SELECT           Item.ItemCode, 
                 Item.ItemDescription, 
                 Purchase.Date, 
                 PurchaseDetails.GRNCode, 
                 PurchaseDetails.ReceivedQty, 
                 Issue.Date AS Expr1, 
                 IssueDetails.MRNCode, 
                 IssueDetails.IssueQty
FROM             Purchase 
INNER JOIN       PurchaseDetails ON Purchase.GRNCode = PurchaseDetails.GRNCode 
INNER JOIN       Item ON PurchaseDetails.ItemCode = Item.ItemCode
INNER JOIN       IssueDetails ON IssueDetails.ItemCode = Item.ItemCode
INNER JOIN       Issue ON Issue.MRNCode = IssueDetails.MRNCode
WHERE            (Item.ItemCode = 10001)
GROUP BY PurchaseDetails.GRNCode
ORDER BY Purchase.Date asc;
```

It looks like you forgot your ON clause when joining the issue table.

I added the ORDER BY Purchase.Date asc clause to order your results by date in ascending order.

Please let me know if this help you :)

Comment: Thank you for immediate answer 
But still output same

Comment: @user2334590, could you try the new query? I would like to see if the GroupBy helps you or not.  If not, is it possible to get a backup of your database?

Comment: I tried but this error message show - Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'PurchaseDetails.GRNCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
I can backup the database and it is a dummy db

Comment: Could you please send me a backup of your DB?  I'll be better able to help then.  I apologize that it's taking so long :/